# NodeJS+Express: redirect doesn't load the endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, firefox

I have a basic e-commerce web application in localhost developed with nodejs and express, admins have to register and then they can add, edit and remove products from the product list.

I have the following endpoints:

```
/signup  
/signin  
/admin/products <- products list endpoint  
/admin/products/new  
/admin/products/:id/edit <- product edition endpoint
```

When admins signs up they are automatically logged in and redirected to the product list endpoint.

```js
router.post('/signup',      
  async (req, res) => {       
    const {email, password, passwordConfirmation} = req.body;
    const user = await usersRepo.create({ email, password });
    req.session.userId = user.id;
    res.redirect('/admin/products');
  })
```

When admins edit a product and then click the submit button, they are also redirected to the product list end point.

```js
router.post('/admin/products/:id/edit',      
  async(req, res) => {
    const changes = req.body;
    await productsRepo.update(req.params.id, changes);
    res.redirect('/admin/products');
  }
);
```

This is the code of the get part for the /admin/products end point

```js
router.get('/admin/products',
  async (req, res) => {
    console.log('loading products page...');
    const products = await productsRepo.getAll();
    res.send(productIndexTemplate({products}))
 });
```

My issue is that when I register a new admin or edit a product, almost always the application doesn't redirect me to the corresponding endpoint(`/admin/products`), instead the browser shows me a 'Unable to connect' page. However in both cases the actions are performed just fine, the new admin account is created and in the case of the product the changes are updated, in fact **if I refresh the page it loads just fine**.

Inspecting the headers I can see that there are requested headers for `/admin/products` but no response headers and also there is no status code, whereas in the case of the referring page (e.g. `/admin/products/:id/edit`) there are both request and response headers. So correct me if I'm wrong but it seems that the server is responding to the request to load /admin/products but for some reason it never loads automatically (I have to manually refresh it).

Now on the other hand the signin endpoint works just fine, so it seems that the problem appears when the application needs to write to my hard drive (creating a new admin user or updating products information)

I've omitted the validators, middlewares, etc in the code for simplicity sake.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set them admin products endpoints as get. I only see post

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  // If user is already logged in, then redirect to rooms page
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.redirect('/rooms');
  }
  else{
    res.render('login', {
      success: req.flash('success')[0],
      errors: req.flash('error'), 
      showRegisterForm: req.flash('showRegisterForm')[0]
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I omitted the get part of the endpoint for simplicity, but I will add it to prevent confusion

Comment: when you use res.send, is use to send data like jsons, if you want to display a page you need to use render instead, also add the header `content-type`:`text/html`

Comment: if your express is a restful api you need to redirect from the client, as the back only dispatches data

Comment: But the page (/admin/products) loads just fine with send() when I type the url manually in the browser or when I reach there from a <a> link, is just when I use redirect(/admin/products) that I have the issue. 

And no, is not a restful api.

Comment: But is not the same thing. When you redirect the status code is 301 not 200 which is the default status code and the content type needs to be text/html